# CSRF With Google Client PHP Authentication Flow

Tags: php, csrf, google-api-php-client, openid-connect, google-openid

I am integrating Google Sign in with [Open ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow). The documentation says that I need to create an anti-forgery state token. I have read several references about CSRF ([Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/preventing-cross-site-request-forgeries/), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSRF%20%28Cross-site%20request%20forgery%29%20php), [Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries)) and a couple more. I can't finish understanding how I am supposed to implement this solution.

I am pretty sure that I haven't understood properly the concept but I am trying hard. This is the process that I have coded so far:

```
<?php session_start(); 

//INCLUDE PHP CLIENT LIBRARY
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$scopes = array('email', 'profile');

// Create client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);
$client->setAccessType("offline");

if( isset($_SESSION["access_token"]) && $_SESSION["access_token"]) {

  if(isset($_SESSION['tokencsrf']) && $_SESSION['tokencsrf'] !== "") {

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]);

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $refreshTokenTxt = "refreshToken.txt";
      $tokenHandle = fopen($refreshTokenTxt, "r");
      $refreshToken = fread($tokenHandle, filesize($refreshTokenTxt));
      $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]);
    }

    $objOAuthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

    $userData = $objOAuthService->userinfo->get();

    var_dump($userData); 

  } else {    
    die(" --- INVALID CSRF! ---");    
  }    

} else {

  $_SESSION['tokencsrf'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

  if( !isset($_GET["code"]) ){

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  } else {

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    $refreshTokenTxt = "refreshToken.txt";

    if (!file_exists($refreshTokenTxt)) {
      $tokenHandle = fopen($refreshTokenTxt, "w");
      fwrite($tokenHandle, $_SESSION['access_token']["refresh_token"]);
    }

    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

  }
}

?>
```

Of course, this is a test script to see if this is the proper way of doing it. So far it works good but I am not sure if this is the correct way. I am kindly requesting support from someone that can confirm if this is ok to use or what changes can be suggested. For your valuable input, I am very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so ashamed of myself right now. The documentation was very clear but my mind was not. The CSRF is implemented by passing the "state" parameter to the client object.

```
$state = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
$_SESSION["state"] = $state;
// Create client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setState($state);
```

Then, after the authentication is done, just confirm the returned token is the same as in the session.

```
if( $_GET["state"] == $_SESSION["state"]) {
    //do stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe $_GET["state"] is used any longer. On my latest test (2022), Google  only returns code, scope, authuser, prompt